no common ratio in sequence but its multiplicative

Number "D" increases 1.25 times per minute.
Number "H" Decreases by "D" every second.
"P" Equals "D" at t=0
"H" increase by "P" every 5 seconds suddenly.
Make t the subject of a formula where by inputting "H" and "P" produces the first time "H" would hit 0.

I'm a bit embarrassed with this one but I've been at it a few hours with excel and desmos.
I used random numbers such as H being 29200 and P being 3000 just to get an idea of a re-arrangement. However even with these I cant find the quadratic to even re-arrange.
I've been circling (1.25^(1/60))/(1.25^(2/60))=1.003725983
do this again at t=2 and 2=3 you get 1.007466.
1.007466/1.003726=1.003725983.
Sorry I waffled for quite some time here so I just deleted it as it was going no where. Hopefully its a simple thing I've forgotten how to do.

How is your question related to [tag:sequences-and-series]?

Incomprehensible. $H$ decreases by $D$ every second, but it also increases by $P$ every five seconds – how is it possible for $H$ to both decrease and increase at the same time? Does "decrease by $D$" mean it becomes $H/D$, or does it mean it becomes $H-D$? What does "it's multiplicative" mean?

H-D every second but as D keeps getting bigger every second by 1.25^1/60. So its multiplying a ratio of itself every second so I cant find a way to make a formula.
Every 5 seconds its H+P but P is a constant. Its nearly a geometric sequence and you can look at it like Nth term but with T instead of N.

I think you can think of it as a two layered geometric series using 1.003726 as shown above, the ratio of the ratio. But when i try to graph it as a quadratic i get.
Y=(1.003726/2!)x^2 + bx +600 (using the example numbers i picked. But anything i use for b doesn't fit the curve
